# How to segue from a custom delegate and datasource

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I have a view with 2 tableviews in it. This view has the controller PlayerDetailController
Now to control the 2 tableviews I have 2 other controllers.

- tablePlayersDataSourceDelegate
- tablePlayerNewsDataSourceDelegate

I ctrl-dragged from the PlayerDetail view to the newsView to make a segue. In my tablePlayerDataSourceDelegate I've the following methods to preform this segue.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPlayerDetailNews" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
    PlayerNews *news = [_tableSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // ask NSFRC for the NSMO at the row in question
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"show detail"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:news.image]];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsTitle:news.title];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsDescription:news.content];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsCopy:news.image_copyright];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsUrl:news.url];
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsShortDescription:news.summary];
    }
}
```

But when I test I get the following error.

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<tblPlayerNewsDatasourceDelagete: 0x1e5e44c0>) has no segue with identifier 'showPlayerDetailNews''
```

I get why this is giving the error. Because the playerDetail view uses the class playerDetailController and I am trying to do te segue in the tablePlayerNewsDelegate class. Do you maybe know a way to work around it?

**EDIT**
Here you see a [picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8105968134/in/photostream) of what I am talking about

So you can see the two tableviews in the playerDetailView. When a cell in the bottom tableview is clicked it should go to the next view.

**EDIT2**

This is what I do in my playerDetailController to fill up my tableview. I've put this in my viewDidLoad.

```
tabelPlayerNews=[[tblPlayerNewsDatasourceDelagete alloc]init];
[tabelPlayerNews setTableSource:_newsArray];
tblNews.dataSource=tabelPlayerNews;
tblNews.delegate=tabelPlayerNews;
tabelPlayerNews.view=tabelPlayerNews.tableView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand that or not but in general....

To use `performSegueWithIdentifier:` the drag for the segue should start at the **controller** that will make the call, not at a view or other object.  I think that's what the error message is telling you: assuming there's a segue called "showPlayerDetailNews" in your storyboard, it doesn't belong to the correct object.

Comment: Okay, let me explain it again. I have a view controller with 2 tableviews in it. But those tableviews have a seperate controller class for their datasource and delegate. In that Controller I am using the performSegueWithIdentifier: . But that controller don't has a visual view in storyboard. So i'm not able to ctrl drag it from this.

Comment: I've edited my questions. I've you need more clarification, please ask.

Comment: Got it.  My answer remains about the same: the drag of the segue has to start at some UIViewController subclass and the call to perform the segue needs to be in that same subclass.  (The existence of data sources and delegates isn't really part of this mechanism.)

Comment: MM oké, but what do you suggest then? I need give data through the next view controller.

Comment: Once the segue is working, look at asking the `tablePlayerNewsDataSourceDelegate` for data to pass to the next controller.  I don't know from what you've posted whether `PlayerDetailController` has a link to that object but it will need one to make the `prepareForSegue:` work.

Comment: Okay so what I need to do is, in my tablePlayerNewsDataSource create an array with the newsItem that is selected and give it back to the controller that calls the segue? right?